# Mostrar texto en un TextBox de XtraUserControl

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Tengo un GridControl en un form y un `XtraUserControl`, en el evento `DoubleClick` de la grilla cargo unos datos a un textbox del `XtraUserControl`, trae los datos correctamente pero no los muestra.

Este es el método que utilizo:

```
Public Sub CargaConsulta(ByVal id As Integer, txt As TextBox)
    Dim sConex As New SqlConnection
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ComandoSql 
                         FROM dbo.Ad_Consultas
                         WHERE Sec_Consulta = @id"
    CadCon = Me.CadConex
    sConex.ConnectionString = CadCon
    Dim sqlComan As New SqlCommand(sql, sConex)
    sqlComan.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
    Try
        sConex.Open()
        Dim leer As SqlDataReader = sqlComan.ExecuteReader
        If leer.Read Then
            txt.Text = Convert.ToString(leer("ComandoSql"))
        End If
        leer.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Desde aquí llamo a `CargarConsulta`:

```
Private Sub VistaConsultas_DoubleClick(senede As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles VistaConsultas.DoubleClick
    CargarConsulta(id, xtrausercontrol.txtscripsql)        
End Sub
```

La cuestión es que en el seguimiento me muestra el valor que trae normal pero no lo carga.

*Nota: ya hice pruebas con un botón para asignar valor con un clic y tampoco me funciono, no se si estos controles tengan algún tipo de restricciones.*

Answer (score 2):

No deberias pasar ningun control al metodo para asignar su valor, sino que deberias implementar algo como ser

```
Public Sub CargaConsulta(ByVal id As Integer) As String

    Using sConex As New SqlConnection(Me.CadConex)
        sConex.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT ComandoSql 
                             FROM dbo.Ad_Consultas
                             WHERE Sec_Consulta = @id"

        Dim sqlComan As New SqlCommand(sql, sConex)
        sqlComan.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)

        Dim leer As SqlDataReader = sqlComan.ExecuteReader
        If leer.Read Then
            Return Convert.ToString(leer("ComandoSql"))
        End If

        Return ""

    End Using

End Sub
```

Veras que el metodo devuelve un string y desde el evento lo asignas al control

```
Private Sub VistaConsultas_DoubleClick(senede As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles VistaConsultas.DoubleClick

    Try

        Dim command As String = CargarConsulta(id)  

        xtrausercontrol.txtscripsql.Text = command

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

De esta forma la responsabilidad del metodo es devolver un resultado obtenido de la db. Sera el evento quien lo asigne al control